# Oracle ROLLBACK versus TRUNCATE TABLE

Tags: oracle, rollback, truncate, dml

I've got two temporary tables, a first level JOIN across 5 tables and a couple hundred thousand rows down to a table with 6 columns and something less than 10k rows. As the user in one session uses filters, I have a second temporary table that contains the filtered results, those filters change per the end-user's whim.

Every time the filters change, I need to TRUNCATE the filtered table and recreate it from the first table.

In essence, I'm bound by permissions, DBA does not want to give me TRUNCATE permissions on a TEMPORARY TABLE.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE 1=1;
```

Is just the wrong method (*though works, admittedly*). Closing and opening a new session has me lose the first table, opening a second session for the second table keeps me from having access to the first.

Using SQL Developer, it looks like DELETE and ROLLBACK take roughly the same time, maybe a slight advantage to ROLLBACK.

The general question is,

> What do you recommend? Am I wrong in my understanding of some of this?

Specific questions:

> Which is better, ROLLBACK or DELETE (on a temporary table)?
>
> Are the roles so narrowly controlled/defined in Oracle that we need to restrict TRUNCATE on a temporary table?

BTW: This is a PeopleSoft system so everyone involved is hyper-sensitive to permissions and roles

Comment: So, you're not committing the first insert? When you say temporary do you mean an actual global temporary table or just one that isn't part of your final data model?

Comment: Where do two sessions come into it? If these are both global temporary tables the data in both of them is private to each session. So I'm not quite sure what you're trying to compare. What problem are you really tryign to solve? You want to keep the first GTT contents while replacing the second GTT's? What transaction control (commit/rollback) are you using at the moment? And how are they defined, particularly the `on commit` clauses?

Comment: Yes, I'm committing the first insert. Yes a GTT.

Comment: OK, so why is rolling back the insert on the second GTT a problem? Are you asking if rollback or *truncate* is better, rather than rollback or delete? They perform the same for me in some quick tests, with delete much slower, but YMMV.

Comment: That's correct, I can't use a second session because the GTT is local to the individual sessions. And the COMMIT/ROLLBACK issues are out of my hands though I can ask for changes. It's configured for “ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS”

Comment: Why are you looking at a second session at all though? If you're using GTTs then all your user's interaction with both tables has to be in one session anyway. I dont' see the connection between sessions and commit/rollback, or indeed delete/truncate.

Comment: @AlexPoole It's not a problem. I know TRUNCATE is what I'd rather use but the DBA is limiting me, I was wondering if ROLLBACK is close in performance but doesn't appear so.

Comment: Yes, I agree a second session doesn't work unless the first table is not a GTT.

Comment: But you've been comparing **delete** with rollback. How are you comparing truncate with rollback if you don't have that privilege - on a different database, or different tables? In my testing of a GTT with 100k rows, rollback and truncate are almost identical, with delete much slower.

Comment: @AlexPoole Cool then, you just answered my question. ROLLBACK in this case is an acceptable replacement for TRUNCATE when you're not given permissions. Only issue is it's not as transparent as to what I'm doing, made more transparent with enough comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing on 11.2.0.4:

```
create global temporary table gtt (id number) on commit preserve rows;

insert into gtt42 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;

prompt rollback
set timing on
rollback;
set timing off;

insert into gtt select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;

prompt delete
set timing on
delete from gtt;
set timing off;

insert into gtt select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;

prompt truncate
set timing on
truncate table gtt;
set timing off;

rollback
Elapsed: 00:00:00.049
delete
Elapsed: 00:00:01.036
truncate
Elapsed: 00:00:00.052
```

Rollback is about the same as truncate, and both are much faster than delete. Logically truncate and rollback are doing pretty much the same thing.

For your scenario it seems to you just need to commit the insert into the first GTT, then repeatedly rollback and insert into the second:

```
create global temporary table gtt1 (id number) on commit preserve rows;
create global temporary table gtt2 (id number) on commit preserve rows;

insert into gtt1 (id) select level from dual connect by level <= 100;
commit;

insert into gtt2 (id) select id from gtt1 where mod(id, 2) = 0;

select count(*), min(id), max(id) from gtt2;

  COUNT(*)    MIN(ID)    MAX(ID)
---------- ---------- ----------
        50          2        100

rollback;

insert into gtt2 (id) select id from gtt1 where mod(id, 3) = 0;

select count(*), min(id), max(id) from gtt2;

  COUNT(*)    MIN(ID)    MAX(ID)
---------- ---------- ----------
        33          3         99
```

The `commit` preserves the rows in the first GTT; the `rollback` then only affects the data in the second GTT and doesn't touch the first.

---

As for the privileges, [from the documentation for `truncate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html):

> To truncate a table, the table must be in your schema or you must have the DROP ANY TABLE system privilege.

As you can't truncate the tables presumably aren't in your schema; and you can hopefully understand why your DBA wouldn't want to give you the very powerful and dangerous `drop any table` privilege. You can't grant a privilege to allow only truncation of a specific table in another schema.

Comment: Thanks, I'll chalk that up to flawed logic from Oracle then. That they can't separate privileges based on something existing only within one session defies logic completely. BTW: I'd +1 you if I had enough "reputation"

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. You can truncate a GTT you own and it only affects the current session.Allowing you to truncate a GTT you don't own (but only a GTT, not a permanent table) would mean they're treated differently, possibly in unexpected ways. Truncate is relatively dangerous so I don't really mind it being restricted. I guess the ability to grant truncate on individual tables might be useful; at a push you could user a wrapper procedure with a dynamic SQL call to truncate, but that's getting messy...

Comment: Actually, I tried to TRUNCATE a GTT I own and, no, it doesn't allow me to do that. Permissions.

Comment: @DannyHolstein - there isn't a privilege that controls that; maybe your DBAs have added a DDL trigger to block it? Going rather off-topic though... *8-)

Answer (score 0):

The DBA is right not to grant you the TRUNCATE permission. The reason? While the method you're using may not be *ideal* for *you*, it does allow you to complete your task **without granting you unnecessary permissions**. Many organizations abide by the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), and if your organization is one of the many that do, the DBA is simply doing their job.

Furthermore, truncates, rollbacks and deletes are different operations for the database. For example, when you delete a record, the database removes that record from the table in question AND also generates rollback segments. When you truncate a table, that rollback is no longer generated, which can prevent you from recovering the data in the event of a failure, which may violate your organization's retention policy. Similarly, performing a rollback doesn't just change data in the temporary table - [it also generates redo information](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=rollback-and-redo). If you are not able to determine these differences, why should the DBA grant you these privileges?

Generally speaking, the best method will vary on a lot of variables - what is your recovery retention policy? Is your organization low on disk space, making the DBA weary of generating too much log information? Are there performance goals that need to be met? There are many factors that could have an impact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is TRUNCATE on a GTT any kind of "**unnecessary permissions**"?
Do you understand that these tables are merely a scratch space to boil down a super complicated JOIN to something manageable and for the length of the session only?

Comment: Are you sure rollback on a GTT generates redo? I'm seeing it on delete and truncate but *not* on rollback, using Tom's query.

Comment: @DannyHolstein Do you *need* the truncate permission to complete the task? If not, it is unnecessary. Granting you Truncate would also mean granting you additional privileges that you do not need. Alex Poole's answer expanded on this. Good point @ Alex. I'm not sure if this also applies to a temporary table. We rarely use temp objects in my part of the agency.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your first temporary table, you can add the ON COMMIT clause and indicate that the data should be maintained throughout the session.  For the second temporary table the default (i.e., DELETE ROWS clause) should be to truncate when each transaction is committed.

So, when the user changes the search criterion, commit the previous search transaction to have the data truncated. I'm fairly certain Oracle truncates the data rather than deleting the individual rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a caveat to the solution when working with VBA. The ADO object automatically COMMITs all transactions, this invalidates all the logic presented here.

As a workaround, we need .BeginTrans and .CommitTrans

```
myConnection.BeginTrans:
```

and

```
myConnection.CommitTrans:
```

before and after (respectively) the transaction we intend to ROLLBACK.